# Is there a way to change the scale of the model when exporting in GLB format?

Tags: export, transforms, gltf

I was trying to decrease the scale of my model while exporting in GLB format but I couldn't find that option like In the FBX exporter,

[image]

but The GLB exporter doesn't have it

[image]

If you guys have solution to this please do let me know.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The glTF exporter does not have this setting, as of Blender v3.6. You'll need to scale the object before export.

Comment: I hoped that there would some other easy way because I have to export it in different scales in multiple times. I guess there is not other way then.