# avatar scale size parameters are changing while exporting in glb format

Tags: animation, transforms, transform-orientation

we imported house(.fbx) into blender.

Next we imported avatar(.glb) into blender.

We have adjusted the size of the avatar by changing the scale values as shown in the screenshot.

While exporting the scene+ avatar as .glb file, the avatar size is increasing to its original one inspite of resetting the avatar scale values(x,y,z).

adjusted avatar size
[image]

Reset after the exporting the complete scene
[image]

Pls suggest what needs to be done to scale down avatar.

tried this [link](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/300698/is-there-a-way-to-change-the-scale-of-the-model-when-exporting-in-glb-format) but no luck

Thanks
vij

Comment: Why do you have keyframes on the Scale? (Green colour). Did you apply the scale to your objects and armature (Ctrl-A > Scale)?

Comment: if i select Ctrl A >scale, the complete mesh is getting distorted. am i missing anything

Comment: I think we'll need to see your Blend file to see what's going on.. You can share it via https://blend-exchange.com/ following the instructions there to copy the link to it and then edit your question and paste the link into it.

Comment: https://fashion-desings.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/common/casuals/tshirts/userchoice/city.blend

Comment: It's impossible to work out what's going on in that scene because there are so many other objects which appear to have nothing to do with your model and mean the whole file is over 300Meg in size! :^(

Comment: Thanks John for helping us in the hour of need...                                                      am sharing the updated .blend file and .glb file    Once we export the complete scene in glb format the avatar size is getting resized to default parameters 
 https://fashion-desings.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/common/casuals/tshirts/userchoice/houseview.blend

https://fashion-desings.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/common/casuals/tshirts/userchoice/houseview.glb